# Looking for a tv show from the 2000 by Lucas films

Tags: story-identification

Hey I don't remember much but what I do remember is a women in a black trench coat who it's hinted at that she might be a clone or a android controlled by a group of people always accompanied by a black panther who she refers to and has flash backs as her friend perhaps from her childhood or whom it is suggested is in some way integrated with the Panther

Another detail is that while the main character is a antihero she starts to have feelings for a man I think he was a teacher of some kind all I remeber is him doing some kind of demonstration with liquid nitrogen

I also vividly remember the lucasflims logo at the end but they don't seem to have it on their web site

The show aired on teletoon in the 2000 around midnight or so

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Is it [CyberSix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cybersix_%28TV_series%29)?  Originally aired on Teletoon in Sept thru Nov 1999, but likely had replays in 2000.  The lead character CyberSix is an artificially created human.  Although not a trench coat, she wore a black skintight leather leotard and a black cape.  Her younger artificially-created human brother's mind was transferred into a black panther by the evil Von Reichter.

[image]
[image]
[image]

By day she is a *male* school teacher to hide her identity, and interacts with students and other teachers.  At night she dons her costume, and fights the evil plots and constructs of Von Reichter.  She has a love interest in Lucas, but of course that sub-plot is complicated since she is pretending to be a male.

[image]
[image]

I watched the ending credits on Hulu, but there was NOT a LusasFilms logo at the end.

Comment: This sounds like a close match, although I can find no links between CyberSix and LucasFilm. The OP is probably either mis-remembering the logo at the end, or the LucasFilm logo was associated with something else (like a trailer or the channel attached to the show) rather than the show itself.

Comment: It could be as simple as that they remembered the character from the show, Lucas Amato, the biology teacher, and somehow got it mixed into there.